# Method for populating data into a class that calls API endpoints not working

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to call a web api to get some JSON data and parse it into my c# class. I've gotten this part down, but I am having trouble with using the returned data, specifically a field and call a second web api with this field as a parameter and grab the returned data to complete my model. 
The problem is that I get an error when trying to call the GetZendeskOrgID method and the error states that it cannot convert void to int.

What would be the best way to approach this?
Thanks in advance,

Code below:
I've scrubbed sensitive fields with random data so no worries.

```
public static async Task PersonQuery()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Format headers
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // Request token, and append to headers
                await AddiMISTokenToHeaders(client);
                // Query HTTP Service                
                var response = await client.GetAsync(imisBaseURL + "api/IQA?queryName=$/RAEted");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    JObject result = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    var customersJson = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"];
                    var customers = new List<IMISCustomer>();
                    foreach (JObject o in customersJson)
                    {
                        var customerJson = (JArray)o["Properties"]["$values"];
                        customers.Add(BuildiMISCustomer(customerJson));
                    }
                    if (customers.Count >= 1)
                    {


                        var persons = customers.Select(async customer => new ZendeskPerson
                        {
                            Name = customer.FullName,
                            Email = customer.Email,
                            external_id = customer.iMISId,
                            WorkPhone = customer.WorkPhone,
                            Organization_id = await GetZendeskOrgID(customer.CompanyiMISID)

                        });
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);

    public static async Task<dynamic> GetZendeskOrgID(string CompanyiMISID)

        {

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic", "YWUnMzMUZlOFhS");

                var response = await client.GetAsync("https://zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/search.json?external_id=" + CompanyiMISID);
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.ToString(response);
               return Convert.ToInt32(data.organization_id);
            }
        }

public class IMISCustomer
        {
            [JsonProperty("ResultRow")]
            public string ResultRow { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Work Phone")]
            public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Full Name")]
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("iMISId")]
            public string iMISId { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Preferred Phone")]
            public string PreferredPhone { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("CompanyiMISID")]
            public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        }
   public class ZendeskPerson
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("external_id")]
            public string external_id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("phone")]
            public string WorkPhone { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("organization_id")]

            public int Organization_id { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetZendeskOrgID`, the `CompanyID` parameter is likely coming in empty. If you require that it have a value, and if you require that that value is a positive integer, you should put error checking into that method. Something like:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyID)){
    throw new NullReferenceException("CompanyId cannot be Null", CompanyID);
}
var outNum = -1;
var companyIdInt = Int.TryParse(CompanyId, out outNum)? OutNum : -1
if(companyIdInt<0){
    throw new Exception("CompanyId must be a number greater than -1");
}
```

Or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

As error says it is not able to convert void to int because organization_id is expecting integer back form function GetZendeskOrgID()
but you are not returning anything from this function make it return int like this
I am assuming that your response object has integer property so you will have to return it like this

```
 public static async Task<int> GetZendeskOrgID(string CompanyID )

    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", "YMUZlOFhS");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/search.json?external_id=" + CompanyID);

             return response.oganization_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my question. I've changed my method to use a lambda when assigning between the two classes, but I am getting an error that states:

System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Self referencing loop detected for property 'Task' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[ZendeskiMIS.Function1+ZendeskPerson,ZendeskiMIS.Function1+<>c+<<PersonQuery>b__4_0>d]'. Path '[0].StateMachine.<>t__builder'.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace: